# Road sign for merging lanes in Iran: Who has priority?

Tags: iran, traffic

I am currently traveling Iran and unfortunately experienced a car accident at the merge of two lanes. There is a road sign indicating the merge but I cannot see whom it gives priority to. Can someone give advice?

[image: Road sign]

The accident itself happened as the car from the very right lane hit the car coming from the lane to the left in the rear part.

[image: Accident]

Whose fault would this be?

**EDIT**

The policeman told us that because the car coming from the left was hit at the corner and not frontal it is its driver's fault in line with a recent amendment. I cannot see the reasoning behind this. Does anyone else?

Comment: +1 for the wheel-less art.. and for taking a photo of the whole phone and not a screenshot.. just perfect <3

Comment: Should this be on Law.SE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did my driving test in Iran 10 years ago and I don't remember quite well this sign but as far as I know and based on my experience, the car which is ahead has the priority to the one that is behind.

**Edit**:

According to what you said as the situation, once again I'll confirm my reasoning that the front car did not make a mistake. In Iran, driving rules are in line with international standards so the vehicle that hits the vehicle ahead is almost always 100% responsible. Even if the vehicle ahead stops, abruptly, or slows down suddenly, the onus is on the vehicle traveling behind to keep a safe distance (everywhere even in that situation you explained).

Comment: My gut feeling would have been the same. However, the policeman said that because the car in front was hit

Comment: at the angle and not frontal it is the front car driver's fault. He said that is rule that came in place just recently. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: What that officer said to you as the recent rule I guess does not exist, because does not make sense at all. The logic says the vehicle ahead has no control of its back!! If you have time and sufficient evidence stop by the Central Police Department in the town which you are in and lodge your complaint about that officer which I think was a bad guy (Hope I'm wrong) or at least does not know his job description very well. I'm sure it will cost his work for this issue (However this would be a long work).

Comment: Thank you. I will forward this to our driver - the one steering the car in front.

Comment: Feel free to do that!